# visual studio code edit root file

Tags: visual-studio-code

1. visual studio code is a wonderful editor.
2. when I editor a file under root user, it can't save, said no permission, Yes, but why there is no  Pop up box let me input my root password? As I known , the sublime will .
3. visual studio code recommend run as a no-root user. And I don't want run it as root also.

So, is there any grace way to edit other users files? thans your answer.

Answer (score 0):

It works now.  Gives error, asks to save using sudo, and then asks for sudo user password.